# Wondering how to power this motor (universal motor?) with the correct power supply and using a pwm speed controller

Tags: power-supply, motor, pwm, amperage, watts

[image: 120v 60hz motor]
This is a motor that I had lying around and so I did a bit of research and found that it’s most likely a universal motor. As shown, the motor says 120v and 60hz (which I assume is the AC and DC rating?). I did a test by hooking up the two wires to a 9v battery and it ran slowly with low torque(obviously). I ideally want to create a circuit using this motor with a speed controller and a basic wall power supply unit.
Something like this.
[image: PWM]
[image: PSU]
The pwm controller says it is rated 5amps and 90watts, while the basic power supply I was looking at says it is listed for 24v at 2 amps. I know that this is most likely under volting the motor a lot but for my project I don’t need terribly high rpm’s. Additionally the project will be under a little bit of load but for the most part spinning quite freely. I don’t really know how many amps this is going to draw. So my main question for this post is, will this described AC to DC power supply unit and the pwm speed controller work with this motor, or will they be not compatible causing one or more of the devices to overheat/ break? Or will I need a PSU and PWM capable of handling/ suppling greater amps? I can give more details if need be! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know, or at least estimate, how much mechanical power (`P=2Pi*M*n`) your motor needs to deliver to your application. That's also the power your power supply has to deliver electrically (`P=U*I`). Knowing your supply voltage you can then solve `2Pi*M*n=U*I` for current and you have a rough estimate for your power supply requirements.